# Actualizar un row en Table.Adapter

Tags: vb.net

He podido hacer que se inserte nuevas rows a la tabla mediante el siguiente código

```
    Dim newRow As DataRow = AppDataSet.Tables("clientes").NewRow()

    newRow("id") = idNew
    newRow("cliente") = TextBox2.Text
    newRow("nombre") = TextBox3.Text
    newRow("cargo") = TextBox4.Text
    newRow("cuit") = TextBox5.Text
    newRow("telefono") = TextBox6.Text
    newRow("movil") = TextBox7.Text
    newRow("asignado") = TextBox8.Text
    newRow("cuentaDe") = TextBox9.Text
    newRow("provincia") = TextBox10.Text
    newRow("codPostal") = TextBox11.Text
    newRow("paginaWeb") = TextBox12.Text
    newRow("notas") = TextBox13.Text


    AppDataSet.Tables("clientes").Rows.Add(newRow)
    ClientesTableAdapter.Update(newRow)
```

Funciona, pero quiero hacer otro que actualice cuando modifico elementos de un row, con el siguiente código

```
                Dim row As DataRow = AppDataSet.Tables("clientes").Rows(fila)


            row("cliente") = TextBox2.Text
            row("nombre") = TextBox3.Text
            row("cargo") = TextBox4.Text
            row("cuit") = TextBox5.Text
            row("telefono") = TextBox6.Text
            row("movil") = TextBox7.Text
            row("asignado") = TextBox8.Text
            row("cuentaDe") = TextBox9.Text
            row("provincia") = TextBox10.Text
            row("codPostal") = TextBox11.Text
            row("paginaWeb") = TextBox12.Text
            row("notas") = TextBox13.Text
```

Al final de este no encuentro que poner para que la tabla se actualice con esta row modificada, en el datagrid se ve la modificación pero claramente necesito usar el tableAdapter de alguna forma para actualizar este row.

Usé ClientesTableAdapter.Update(row) y da error "Update requiere que UpdateCommand sea válido cuando se pasa la colección DataRow con filas modificadas."

No me doy una idea de como hacer que en la bd solo actualice ese row.

Comment: Me parece que estas confundiendo algo. Si actualizaste los valores, la fila ya esat actualizada. Vos hablas de actualizar la DB?

Comment: eso mismo, actualizar la DB necesito.

Comment: podria inferir que no probaste pasarle a ClientesAdapter esta fila y hacer un update a ver que pasaba?

Comment: nose como ponerlo, yo lo puse ClientesTableAdapter.Update() o ClientesTableAdapter.Update(row) y da error

Comment: que error? pon toda la informacion completa en la pregunta, lo que intentaste y no anduvo tambien, si no te vamos a recomendar que hagas algo que ya hiciste, y tal vez solo lo hiciste mal.

Comment: editado, con el error "Update requiere que UpdateCommand sea válido cuando se pasa la colección DataRow con filas modificadas."

Comment: exactamente.. y tu updatecommand esta definido? supongo que no.

Comment: no, como lo defino?

Comment: Como no tenes una key principal no lo puede inferir. tenes que reveer como funciona EF. Como puede saber que registro tiene que modificar, si no tiene una clave contra la cual validar el registro?

Comment: ahi hice, y ahora da error "ExecuteReader: no se ha inicializado la propiedad CommandText"